# What are some interesting feeds for the chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Chat rooms allow setting up RSS feeds which show up in the room as chat messages or in a ticker (overlay). I think setting up feeds from interesting sources would help towards generating interest in the room and create topics to discuss.
As far how many feeds to set up is concerned, I think there should be atmost 2-3 *offsite* blogs or sources added.

So, what are some interesting feeds that we could set up in the chat room?

---

#### Active Feeds

- Main site new questions (ticker)
- Meta site active questions (chat)

Answer (score 1):

### The Arduino [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/arduino).

They have a lot of interesting blog posts (from many sites including their own). They seem to only post a few times a day, so we wouldn't be overwhelmed with posts. However, I would still recommend using a ticker, especially for Arduino Day 2014, where there will probably be a lot more tweets during that event.

***How do we get a feed into our site?***

First of all, any moderator from any site can edit the feeds as a ticker or a chat message. (Ticker: dismissible banner at the top of the screen, chat message isn't deletable and is in the *main* section of the chat window.)

The harder part is getting a Twitter RSS feed. Don't worry, I've got ideas. [RSS 4 Twitter](http://www.rssitfor.me/about.html) is ran on open source software and donations, and is free. So far, it only works for **users, not hashtags**. Still, we can get the [Arduino RSS feed (link to RSS data, not to Twitter)](http://www.rssitfor.me/getrss?name=arduino). There's no account involved, so it's no big deal to add it into the chat room. The owners claim it is updated every 90 minutes, which may be a lot if you are subscribed to Arduino already, but it's better than nothing, and is the only way to get a RSS feed for the Arduino blog.